# Cómo comparar dos cadenas de longitud diferente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estoy bloqueado con este ejercicio que consiste, básicamente, en comparar pares de cadenas que pueden tener la misma longitud o no.

Una vez que hayas leído la situación así como visto mi programa, te darás cuenta de que mi dificultad reside en el hecho de que no logro mostrar, en el caso de que ambos jugadores quedan empatados, quién es el ganador por tener todavía cartas.

Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.

### Aquí te comparto la situación:

Debes escribir un programa de computadora para determinar el ganador de este juego de cartas.

Una partida se desarrolla de esta manera:

Partimos de un juego que contiene 52 cartas, cada carta es una letra entre A y M, y cada letra está presente 4 veces.
Las cartas, boca abajo, se mezclan y se separan en dos paquetes (¡no necesariamente del mismo tamaño!).
Ambos jugadores devuelven la primera carta de su mazo: si las dos cartas son idénticas, continúan jugando; de lo contrario, la que tenga la carta más fuerte, es decir, la más pequeña en orden alfabético, gana la partida.
Si un jugador no tiene más cartas, pierde! Y sí, no es muy justo!
Si ambos jugadores no tienen más cartas al mismo tiempo, entonces hay un empate.
Dados los dos paquetes de cartas, depende de usted determinar el ganador.

ENTRADA

La entrada contiene dos líneas, correspondientes respectivamente a las cartas del jugador 1 y del jugador 2, en orden. Un mazo de cartas consiste solo en letras mayúsculas entre A y M (sin espacios).

SALIDA

En la primera línea, indique "1", "2" o "=" dependiendo de si el ganador es el primero o el segundo jugador, o si hay empate.

En la segunda línea, indique la cantidad de empates que tuvieron lugar antes de que terminara el juego.

Ejemplo 1:

Entrada:
AABBDCCDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMM
AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMM

Salida:

2

4

Ejemplo 2:

Entrada:
AA
AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMMBBDCCDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMM

Salida:

2

2

Comentarios:
El ejemplo 1 es el siguiente:

A contra A, empate;
A contra A, empate;
B contra B, empate;
B contra B, empate;
D contra C: C gana.
Por lo tanto, es el jugador 2 el que gana el juego, después de 4 empates.

En el ejemplo 2, después de dos empates, el jugador 1 no tiene más cartas y, por lo tanto, pierde el juego.

### Y mi código:

```
jugador_1 = input()
jugador_2 = input()
num_empates = 0

if (len(jugador_1) < len(jugador_2)) or (len(jugador_1) == len(jugador_2)):
    for i in range(len(jugador_1)):
        if (jugador_1[i] < jugador_2[i]):
            print(1)
            break
        elif (jugador_1[i] > jugador_2[i]):
            print(2)
            break
        elif (jugador_1[i] == jugador_2[i]):
            num_empates += 1
        i += 1
else:
    for i in range(len(jugador_2)):
        if (jugador_1[i] < jugador_2[i]):
            print(1)
            break
        elif (jugador_1[i] > jugador_2[i]):
            print(2)
            break
        elif (jugador_1[i] == jugador_2[i]):
            num_empates += 1
        i += 1

print(num_empates)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu solución presenta un [*code smell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)  en forma de código repetido. Todo lo que tienes dentro del `for` que hay en el `if`, es idéntico a lo que aparece en el `for` del `else`. El código repetido es un síntoma de que las cosas pueden hacerse de un modo mejor.

Entiendo que en tu caso buscas determinar quién tiene menos cartas, para iterar ese número de veces. Una forma más simple sería calcular de antemano cuál es el mínimo entre `len(jugador_1)` y `len(jugador_2)`, y luego iterar en base a ese mínimo. Es decir:

```
iteraciones = min(len(jugador_1), len(jugador_2))
for i in range(iteraciones):
    if (jugador_1[i] < jugador_2[i]):
        print(1)
        break
    elif (jugador_1[i] > jugador_2[i]):
        print(2)
        break
    elif (jugador_1[i] == jugador_2[i]):
        num_empates += 1
```

Por cierto que sobraba el `i+=1` que haces al final, ya que de todas formas en cada iteración del bucle la `i` irá tomando un nuevo valor de los que `range()` va devolviendo. También el último `elif` sobra ya que si no es el caso primero ni el segundo, es que son iguales.

Cuando abandones el bucle anterior puede ser debido a que uno de los jugadores ya ha ganado, o a que se han terminado las cartas. Necesitas poder distinguir ambos casos. Lo más sencillo puede ser que, en lugar de hacer un `print(1)` o `print(2)`, tengas una variable llamada `ganador` que antes de empezar vale 0 y dentro del bucle le das el valor `1` ó `2`. Si agotado el bucle la variable sigue siendo cero, es que al jugador con menos cartas se le han acabado. Por tanto el otro será el vencedor, a menos que ambos tuvieran el mismo número de cartas, en cuyo caso sería un empate.

Implementando esta idea:

```
iteraciones = min(len(jugador_1), len(jugador_2))
ganador = 0
for i in range(iteraciones):
    if (jugador_1[i] < jugador_2[i]):
        ganador = 1
        break
    elif (jugador_1[i] > jugador_2[i]):
        ganador = 2
        break
    else:
        num_empates += 1

# Si se agotaron las cartas
if ganador == 0:
   # Hay que mirar quién terminó antes sus cartas para proclamar un ganador
   if len(jugador_1) == len(jugador_2):
      ganador = "="   # Empate, acabaron las cartas a la vez
   else:
      if len(jugador_1) < len(jugador_2):
         # El jugador 1 terminó sus cartas
         ganador = 2
      else:
         ganador = 1

# Ahora basta imprimir los resultados
print(ganador)
print(num_empates)
```

Comment: Decididamente he aprendido con cada línea de código que propones. Como no lograba imprimir el ganador tras un empate, toda solución que proponía afectaba la impresión final. De haber encontrado yo solo la respuesta, no habría  tenido la oportunidad de poder reciclar mi código de esta forma. La primera línea, wow, me ahorra casi la mitad de líneas y aligera el programa. Gracias por tu ayuda!!!